# Why won't my app render when state changes?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building an application that allows for posting community concerns with the ability to upvote those concerns using React, and right now, I am working on the upvote functionality.  One way I'm trying to limit the currently logged in user to a single vote is to disable the button once an upvote has been successfully registered for any given post.

To do this, I created a function that checks if the logged in user's ID matches the ID of the upvote for each post.  If no match is found, this means the user hasn't voted for already and can register the new upvote.  Once this is complete, the button is disabled.  I created state for this and is set to false upon the initial render (not sure if this is what I should be doing).  I also created state for the all of the votes that have been successfully registered.  Both are included below.

```
const [alreadyVoted, setAlreadyVoted] = useState(false);
const [userVotes, setUserVotes] = useState(upvotes) // upvotes is being passed via props
```

I'm using the useEffect hook (again, not sure if this is the best way) to check if each button should be enabled or disabled like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  hasVoted()
}, [userVotes])
```

Finally, my hasVoted function checks to see if the user has already voted for the issue before and determines the state.  It looks like:

```
function hasVoted() {
  userVotes.forEach(vote => {
    if (vote.issue_id === issue.id) {  // issue here is from props
      setAlreadyVoted(true) // I want this to then disable my button
    }
  })
}
```

Right now, when I click the button to register the upvote, the page doesn't rerender upon clicking.  However, if I refresh the page, the button is successfully disabled as it should be.  It probably goes without saying, I'm still getting the hang of React, but any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: is there any error in browser console

Comment: did you check in debugger that this code is executed? setAlreadyVoted(true)

Answer (score 1):

This code is meaningless at first place

```
userVotes.forEach(vote => {
    if (vote.issue_id === issue.id) {  // issue here is from props
      setAlreadyVoted(true) // I want this to then disable my button
    }
  })
```

, it can be transformed into

```
if (userVotes.some(vote => vote.issue_id === issue.id)) setAlreadyVoted(true)
```

but still the logic of it is not clear

Answer (score 0):

I think hasVoted function should be in the useEffect scope. If it's outside, it might introduce bugs, as documented here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies

You could try if this helps to resolve your problem

Comment: Just tried that and I'm still having the same problem.  Thanks for linking to the docs though.  I'll have to read through again!

Comment: maybe you can show us the parent and child component logic to fully understand the problem. From your post, declaring userVotes and setVotes again in the child seems redundant as the state is controlled from the parent already

Comment: I just fixed it.  I needed to update the dependency array in the useEffect hook in the parent component that was initially fetching all the upvotes for the logged in user.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be somewhat on the right track here but your problem  may lay elsewhere,provided the props are passed correctly,because the application does re-render when the state changes. if you want to just disable button you can just use simple html attribute to do that

```
    {alreadyVoted ? (
        <button class="btn btn-success" disabled="disabled">
          Upvote
        </button>
      ) : (
        <button
          class="btn btn-success"
          onClick={() =>
        // Add the id to the setUserVotes here    
       setAlreadyVoted(true)}
        >
          Upvote
        </button>
      )}
```

Take a look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-architecture-nbh8p?file=/src/App.js:751-1076) that i just created and get back to me if you have any issues still